# Open multiple windows after verify php condition

Tags: php, javascript, windows, ajax

i have the file 1.html:

```
.....


 <script src="/libs/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var url0='{$url0}';
    var url1='{$url1}';
    var url2='{$url2}';
    var url3='{$url3}';
    var OPEN_ON = false;
    openurls= function(){
    if(confirm('Opens all?') && OPEN_ON == false){
                    OPEN_ON = true;
    $.ajax({<br/>
        type: "POST",
        url: "a1.php",
        data: jsonData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            success = true;

        },
        error: function(msg) {

        }
    })

    if(success) { 
     window.open(url0)
     window.open(url1)
    window.open(url2)
    window.open(url3) 
    }


                 setTimeout("location.reload(true);",3000) 

                    OPEN_ON = false
                }
                return false

    }
```

Question is:
How do I send url0, url1, url2 and url3 to the file a1.php and there after checking some conditions to send them back.`enter code here`

Comment: @user505848...Welcome to SO... There is a nifty button with 1's and zeros at the top of the editor window.  This button allows you to select your code then click the button and it will format the code for you.  Also for Code blocks you can simply put 4 spaces in front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put those `window.open()` calls *inside* the "success:" callback function.

Now, once you do that, you're going to find that the new windows don't actually open.  The browsers are going to block them because they look like aggressive popup ads. Because those `window.open` calls are happening in a context other than a direct user-initiated event (like a button click), they'll be blocked. That said, here's what your "success" function should look like:

```
$.ajax({<br/>
    type: "POST",
    url: "a1.php",
    data: { url0: url0, url1: url1, url2: url2, url3: url3 },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      window.open(url0);
      window.open(url1);
      window.open(url2);
      window.open(url3);
    },
    error: function(msg) {

    }
})
```

That will "work" as the `window.open()` calls will be made, but it won't "work" in that you won't actually get popups.  You have to make it such that user activity (a "click" somewhere) makes the windows open, not an XMLHttpRequest state change.

Comment: <strong><br><a href="#" onclick="openurls();return false;">Open all </a></strong>

Comment: How do I send url0, url1, url2 and url3 to the file a1.php and there after checking some conditions to send them back.

Comment: You'd have to send them as parameters to the ajax call. Right now you're sending "jsonData"; I have no idea what that is, but that's where you'd add the parameters.

Comment: I am a novice with AJAX. How do I send url0, url1, url2 and url3 to the file a1.php and there after checking some conditions to send them back.

Comment: You're already sending some parameters in that "jsonData" string (or whatever it is); just add them to that.

Comment: You did not put the code that sets up "jsonData" in your question, so I don't know what it looks like and therefore I can't tell you exactly.  I'll edit my answer to include an example.

Comment: i want to send to a1.php url0...url3 and verify in my sql database if this urls are equal with "google.com" they become "yahoo.com"

Comment: Look, I hope you find some help locally. You may want to spend some time reading the jQuery documentation and examples, and maybe look for some jQuery AJAX tutorials. I've already given you as much of an example as can be useful, because I don't know how your server code works (and I don't even know php).